# Upload two column excel data with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can upload a .csv file into my database when it has only column but I keep getting errors when it has two columns.

1.I select CSV and I keep options untouched so Fields terminated by ; Enclosed by "" escaped by \ lines terminated by auto.

```
Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.
```

2.I select CSV using LOAD DATA and keep options untouched

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'aXXXXXX_apps'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

3.I select CSV using LOAD DATA and select *use LOCALE keyword*

```
#1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

4.I select CSV using LOAD DATA and select use LOCALE keyword and select Fields terminated by , since I figured if I open the .csv in notepad I see the two fields in a row are separated by a comma and rows are terminated by new lines e.g.

```
427982779,3050771
974082772,5093681
853347161,4809015
556910392,3195360

#1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

I tried to change the *lines terminated by* field to \r, \n, \r\n but I keep receiving the same error.

I also tried inserting a headings row in the .csv then in the *Column names* field I typed them like ID,USERNAME

Table structure:

```
ID  varchar(10) utf8_general_ci
USERNAME    varchar(15) utf8_general_ci
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Chose the CSV option and change the 'Fields terminated by' to `,`